# ¿Cómo ejecutar función cada cierto tiempo? MVC5 .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Buenas.

Lo que necesito es ejecutar una función todos los lunes, dicha funcion me va a limpiar una carpeta con imágenes. Ya sé cómo limpiar la carpeta, solo necesito saber como hago para programar la ejecución de esa función todos los lunes. El entorno es MVC5 .NET Visual Studio 2015.

Les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Has considerado en utilizar un servicio?

Comment: ¿Es una web app para una Intranet o estará en Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET en general y ASP.NET MVC5 en particular son tecnologías para desarrollar aplicaciones web. Lo que tú estás planteando no tiene nada que ver con una aplicación web.

Yo, para este caso, lo que haría es crear una tarea programada que se ejecute todos los lunes.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista, el detalle es que no debo eliminar todas las imágenes de la carpeta. Solo debo eliminar algunas imágenes en especifico.

Comment: Bien, la tarea programada puede ejecutar un proceso con lógica tan compleja como necesites. Pero sigue sin tener nada que ver con una aplicación web. Si la lógica es simple puedes ejecutar un comando o un proceso por lotes, si es más compleja la tarea programada podría ejecutar una aplicación de consola por ejemplo.